# How to get rid of this gap between consecutive <header> and <main>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesss/pjx21dvL/1/)**

I have an HTML page where the body consists of a `<header>` element followed by a `<main>` element. The problem is that there is a gap/empty-horizontal-space between the `<header>` and `<main>` elements, which is neither any `padding` nor any `margin`.

I need to get rid of this gap. How do I do that?

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<header class="light-blue darken-4">

  <div class="row section">
    <div class="col s12">
      <a href="#" class="button-collapse  grey-text text-lighten-2" data-activates="side-drawer-container"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <span class="container">
                    <a href="#" class="brand-logo grey-text text-lighten-2"> Logo</a>
            </span>
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
  </div>
  <!-- .row -->


  <ul id="side-drawer-container" class="side-nav ">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent center">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#One" class="active">ONE</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#Two">TWO</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#Three">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</header>

<main>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">

      <section id="all"></section>

      <section id="One">
        <div class="row hoverable lime lighten-3">
          <div class="col s12">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent center lime lighten-3">
              <li class="tab"><a href="#amy" class="light-blue-text text-darken-4">Amy</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a href="#bob" class="active light-blue-text text-darken-4">Bob</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a href="#anna" class="light-blue-text text-darken-4">Anna</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a href="#liv" class="light-blue-text text-darken-4">Liv</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- .col -->
        </div>
        <!-- .row -->

        <div id="amy">Amy amy</div>
        <!-- #amy -->
        <div id="bob">Bob bob</div>
        <!-- #bob -->
        <div id="anna">Anna anna</div>
        <!-- #anna -->
        <div id="liv">Liv liv</div>
        <!-- #liv -->
      </section>

      <section id="Two">2
      </section>

      <section id="Three">3
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Are you sure the padding/margin isn't on the `row` class?

Comment: A tip, if you inspect the element (right click and chose `Inspect`), you will be able to _see_ the elements and how they occupy space ... and you also see the CSS ... and if you do that on above snippet, you'll quite fast will find it yourself, the `margin-bottom: 20px` in the `row` rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `margin-bottom: 20px` on `.row` creating that gap. It's the result of "margin collapse" because that `.row` is the last child of `header` and has a margin that is collapsing outside of `header`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

You can either just remove that, or add `overflow: hidden` to `header` if you want the margin to show up inside of `header` instead of outside of it.